# File uploading requires to save full PATH instead of relative

Tags: php, symfony

I'm building a simple rest API endpoint, which expects a file. The controller gets the file and tries to persist an object with it:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="file", type="string")
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\File()
 */
private $file;
```

First of all I generate a file name, and then move the file to it's final folder.

```
$finalRoute = $this->getFileUploadFolder().'/'.$loggedInUser->getId() . '/';
$file->move($finalRoute, $fileName);
```

So now, when I do store the object into the database, I do the following:

```
$modelToPersist->setFile($fileName)
```

And it doesn't work, it does return a:

> [message:Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation:private] => The file could not be found.

Which makes sense, as the URI is not fully qualified, it's just the file name.
However if I do change above code to be

```
$modelToPersist->setFile($finalRoute . $fileName);
```

It does work. However the saved value in database, is a fully qualified URI, like:

> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/api/app/../web/uploads/uploadedFile.txt

As you can imagine, this above URI does the trick, but it's not scalable at all, as if I move the folder with the uploads, everything is screwed. Not only that, but this URI is not the public URL to access this resource...

**Is there any way I can upload the file without having to specify the full URI?** I've thought about just not using that `@File`annotation, and just a `string`field, but then, what's the point of the annotation?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to save a string why do you assert File() ?

the file notation is only for moving the upload while saving you dont need it anymore after that, the advantage is for example validating file size / mime types etc.
you need some other property to store the correct "webpath"

heres some example code

```
public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->src
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->src;
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->src
        ? null
        : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->src;
}

public function setWebPath()
{
    $this->webPath=$this->getWebPath();
    return $this;
}

public function getUploadRootDir()
{
    // The absolute directory path where uplaoded documents should be saved
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getUploadDir()
{
    // Get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn/t screw up when displaying uploaded doc/img in the view
    return '/uploads/documents';
}

/**
 * Sets file
 * 
 * @param UploadedFile $file
 */
public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
{
    $this->file = $file;
}

public function upload()
{
    // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
    if (null === $this->getFile()) {
        return;
    }

    // unique file prepend
    $rand = substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, 5);

    // move takes the target directory and then the
    // target filename to move to
    $this->getFile()->move(
        $this->getUploadRootDir(),
          htmlspecialchars($rand.$this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName())
    );
    $this->src = htmlspecialchars($rand.$this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName());
    $this->setWebPath();

    // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
    $this->file = null;

}
```

Comment: Is `upload()` really a method that should reside in the entity itself rather than eg. a service? Also `uploadDir` sounds like it would better fit in the config or parameters file

Comment: so the answer is actually that the File annotation is worthless to save a file? And it's only useful when rendering a Form?

Comment: no its not worthless, what about that validation and "file-handling" thing? its well described here http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/cookbook/controller/upload_file.html ---- you do not store the file in database, you save it somewhere and in database you have the fileuri